# Polymorphic has_many through Associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following problem,
A user can have several professions, more than 10. For example, a user may be a doctor, teacher, and N. Each profession has its own attributes.
I could do, Doctor belongs_to User, but if I want to know all the professions of this user I will have to check each row of the User table.

I created the following code

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobables
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :jobable
end

class Jobable < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :job
end

class Medic < Jobable
end

class Programmer < Jobable
end
```

But I do not know if that would be the best answer

Comment: can't you do `user.jobables` to get all the professions for a user ?

Comment: You don't seem to be using `polymorphic` anywhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think that it would be much easier to do something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_professions
  has_many :professions, through: :user_professions
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: professions
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                   :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_professions
  has_many :users, through: :user_professions
end

class UserProfession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :profession 
end
```

You could then create logic to ensure that a `Profession` is only assigned to a `User` once.

Then, you could simply do:

```
@user.professions
```

And get all the `Profession`s for a `User`.

You could also do:

```
@profession.users
```

And get all the `User`s that belong to the `Profession`.

Based on the edit to your question, you *could* do something like:

```
class UserProfession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :profession
  belongs_to :profession_detail, polymorphic: true
end
```

In which case you might have something like:

```
class DoctorDetail < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And you could do something like:

```
@user.professional_detail_for(:doctor)
```

Of course, you would need to implement the `professional_detail_for` method on the `User` model which *might* look something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :user_professions
  has_many :professions, through: :user_professions

  def professional_detail_for(profession_type)
    user_profession_for(profession_for(profession_type)).try(:profession_detail)
  end

private

  def profession_for(profession_type)
    Profession.find_by(name: profession_type.to_s)
  end

  def user_profession_for(profession)
    user_professions.find_by(profession: profession)
  end

end
```

That's a little rough, but I imagine you get the idea.