# Only one row representing mutiple models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible in rails to have only one table with one row representing multiple models? For example:

User 1 is a Doctor

User 2 is a Doctor and Teacher

```
 user_id | doctor_id | type_doctor | teacher_id | type_teacher |  
   1         1           true          NULL          NULL
   2         2           true           1            true
```

With that, in just one row I can know what my user is.

Comment: You mean like [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)?

Comment: This is not STI material, I think you approach is wrong.

Comment: nope. one model has a unique id, but can also have foreign keys for the parents it belongs to. Though sometimes you can associate two models in a table: `has_and _belongs_to_many` relationship. But usually it is made of two different models id, not more. (though type teacher and type doctor can be queried from the parents of the two elements the table is made of) Edit : if type doctor and type teacher are relevant to that veruy association, you can probably add them in table by tweaking the `has_and _belog_to_many` table. Though there may be a better technique

Comment: Does `type_x` indicate that `x_id` is not null? BTW, I *think* you mean one row associating multiple role models (e.g., `doctor`, `teacher`, etc.), yes?

Comment: yes @jvillian, in one row i have multiple role models

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 models. `User`, `Doctor` and `Teacher` and not keep information in one place.

```
class User
  has_one :doctor
  has_one :teacher
end

class Doctor
  belongs_to :user
end

class Teacher
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do it that way, but it doesn't make much sense. If you *did* want to do it, you might have something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: role_records
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id      :integer
#  doctor_id    :integer
#  teacher_id   :integer
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#
class RoleRecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  [:doctor, :teacher].each do |role|
    belongs_to role
    define_method("#{role}?") do 
      !send(role).nil?
    end
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :role_record
end

class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :role_record
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :role_record
end
```

In which case, you could do something like:

```
@user.role_record.doctor?
@user.role_record.teacher?
```

This will, of course, barf if `role_record` is `nil`. So, you could do something like:

```
@user.role_record.try(:doctor?)
```

Naturally, that's all completely awful. Besides being a horrendous hack, your `RoleRecord` table is likely to end up sparsely populated.

Why did you decide to give up on the direction from your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223669/polymorphic-has-many-through-associations-in-ruby-on-rails) yesterday?

What is it you're really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a particular user is whether a doctor or an engineer, you can achieve that by creating a `has_many` `through` relationship.

So `Profession` model will contain all the professions, like doctor, teacher, engineer etc. Make sure their ids don't change

In `UserProfessionMapping` model we can create scopes for filtering out records relating to specific professions

In `User` model we'll those roles to determine whether a user is a doctor or a teacher.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # id
  # email
  # ..

  has_many :user_profession_mappings
  has_many :professions, through: :user_profession_mappings

  def is_doctor?
    self.user_profession_mappings.doctor.present?
  end

  def is_teacher?
    self.user_profession_mappings.teacher.present?
  end
end


class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  # Only two columns - >
  # id
  # name
  has_many :user_profession_mappings
  has_many :users, through: :user_profession_mappings

  # Doctor - id: 1
  # Teacher - id: 2
  # Engineer - id: 3

end


class UserProfessionMapping < ApplicationRecord
  # only 2 columns ->
  # user_id
  # profession_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession

  scope :doctor, -> {where profession_id: 1}
  scope :teacher, -> {where profession_id: 2}
  scope :engineer, -> {where profession_id: 3}
end
```

To make add a profession to a user, you'll something like this ->

```
doctor = Profession.find(1) # since id for doctor is 1
@user.professions << doctor
```

Now to check whether a user is a doctor you'll do

```
@user.is_doctor? # will give true
@user.is_teacher? # will give false
```

For more information check out [official documentations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)